# drag and drop of table rows between two similar table in jquery with draggable and droppable

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, tablerow

I am trying to drag a table row and to drop it in the similar table i.e, of same table structure.

I am trying to implement with j query drag-gable but not able to fix it.

I found few [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/Kzf62/85/) links

```
$("tbody.connectedSortable")
    .sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        items: "> tr:not(:first)",
        appendTo: $tabs,
        helper: "clone",
        zIndex: 999990,
        start: function () {
            $tabs.addClass("dragging")
        },
        stop: function () {
            $tabs.removeClass("dragging")
        }
    })
```

but here i dont have a tab for other table.

Answer (score 10):

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yf47u/)

**Jquery**

```
var $tabs = $('#table-draggable2')
$("tbody.connectedSortable")
    .sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        items: "> tr:not(:first)",
        appendTo: $tabs,
        helper: "clone",
        zIndex: 999990
    })
    .disableSelection();
var $tab_items = $(".nav-tabs > li", $tabs).droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable tr",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id='table-draggable1'>
   <tbody class="connectedSortable">
      <tr>
         <th>col1</th>
         <th>col2</th>
         <th>col3</th>
         <th>col4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>156</td>
         <td>668</td>
         <td>100.95</td>
         <td>1.82</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>256</td>
         <td>668</td>
         <td>100.95</td>
         <td>1.82</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table id='table-draggable2'>
   <tbody class="connectedSortable">
      <tr>
         <th>COL1</th>
         <th>COL2</th>
         <th>COL3</th>
         <th>COL4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>356</td>
         <td>668</td>
         <td>100.95</td>
         <td>1.82</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>456</td>
         <td>668</td>
         <td>100.95</td>
         <td>1.82</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If I were to want to submit a post request via ajax to update the table in the database, where would I put it?

Comment: @Pabi place it in the jquery-ui "drop" function. That should handle updating the server's records so that 1) the row doesn't show up in the old table anymore and 2) the row now shows up in the new table, preferably in the order in which it was dropped.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so here is my addition to the previous answer (which is 100% correct). First of all, to update a DB, see [this](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-ui/).
For anyone uninitiated into jquery, you must reference both jquery and jquery.ui to make this work. And you must reference jquery first because jquery.ui references the other. To put it all together, here is a template that you can use to drag and drop contents from the jsfiddle link.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
<!--- insert jquery code from JSFIDDLE here --->
</script>
<style>
<!--- insert CSS code from JSFIDDLE here --->
</style>
<!--- insert HTML code from JSFIDDLE here --->
```