# Drag and Drop multiple rows from html table using Jquery with <thead> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, tablerow

I have two tables in the JsFiddle and I want to swap rows `<tr>` in between them. I want to be able to do this with Jquery however right now, because of the `<thead>` tag, it is not working. I'm thinking it has something to do with `items` in `selector`, but I don't know what to change it to so that it will ignore the `<thead>`. I was wondering how to edit the code so that it can make everything draggable and re-arrange-able except the `<thead>` tags

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yf47u/262/)

in the current jsfiddle, removing the `<thead>` tags will work, however i need the `<thead>` to be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix your HTML code. You must put "thead" tag out of "tbody"
It will work. One more thing, you don't need to use droppable with sortable, remove it. Working version at http://jsfiddle.net/73kv2vm9/1/

```
            <table id='table-draggable1'>  
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>col1</th>
                    <th>col2</th>  
                    <th>col3</th>  
                    <th>col4</th>  
                </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody class="connectedSortable"> 
                <tr>   
                    <td>156</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td>  
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>256</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td> 
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                
                </tr>  
            </tbody> 
        </table>
        <table id='table-draggable2'>  
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>COL1</th>  
                    <th>COL2</th>  
                    <th>COL3</th>  
                    <th>COL4</th>  
                </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody class="connectedSortable">
                <tr>   
                    <td>356</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td>  
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>456</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td> 
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                
                </tr>  
            </tbody> 
        </table>
```

Comment: how come when I drag all tr from one table, I can't put elements back into that empty table? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The reason why you can't put an element on sortable zone is that zone is not visible. I recommend to use "div" or "ul" tags. And you must set width and height for them in case they don't have any child elements.

Comment: Hmm...the problem is that I need to use tr and td. Is there really no way? If tbody can't be adjust can we choose some other space as the sortable zone?

Comment: You can create another sortable, say a hidden div. When your tbody is empty, show the div. In stop event, move the dragged item to tbody.

Comment: I have posted answer for a similar question here [Drag and drop table rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282683/drag-and-drop-multiple-rows-from-html-table-using-jquery/43007409#43007409) , take a look, hope it helps. It has the whole code and demo